# Disable back button in VrVideoView Cardboard-Mode in Android SDK

Tags: android, google-vr

I'm developing an Android app for a controlled environment in which the user should not be allowed to exit the VrVideoView's full screen cardboard mode.

By entering the cardboard mode the SDK seems to present its own activity so I cannot simply override on onBackPressed.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By poking around in the innards you can get your hands on the dialog (yes, it's a dialog) and disable the back button:

```
vrView = (VrVideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
vrView.fullScreenDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.