# [Android]: Remove/Hide back, info and cardboard button from VrVideoView

Tags: android, google-cardboard, vrvideoview

I want to use VrVideoView as a splash screen for my app. For that I want to remove back,info and cardboard buttons(in below image) from VrVideoView.

[image]

Is this possible? If not, is there any other way I can show a 360 video as my splash screen?

I have already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191666/disable-back-button-in-vrvideoview-cardboard-mode-in-android-sdk), but it did not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For Hide/Show Info Button,

> videoWidgetView.setInfoButtonEnabled(true);

For Hide/Show CardBoard Button,

> videoWidgetView.setStereoModeButtonEnabled(true);

For Hide/Show FullScreenButton,

> videoWidgetView.setFullscreenButtonEnabled(true);